# Getting entries from Parse.com of maximum 1 hour difference between current time and added time

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

How can I make a query on Parse.com database to get only the entries that are maximum 1 hour old?

I have this code:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AlertsClass");
            query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
            query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("_created_at", currentDateTimeString);
            try {
                ob = query.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
}
```

But I am stuck. Can someone please help me to do this query properly?

Thank you!

Comment: A few things. 

 1. I believe it's "createdAt" not "_created_at"
 
 2. Why are you overriding doInBackground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Date now = new Date());
long nowMillis = now.getTime();
long oneHourInMills = 3600000;
Date anHourAgo = new Date(nowMillis - oneHourInMillis);
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AlertsClass");
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", anHourAgo);
```